# What does "\_%" mean regarding MySQL database permissions?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a new MySQL user `homestead` using phpMyAdmin and when doing so, created a new database with the same name.  As seen below, `homestead` was given permissions to two databases: `homestead` and `homestead\_%`.

What does the `\_%` signify?  I later created a new database `laravel`, and wish user `homestead` to have the same permissions as the first table.  Do I need to also add permissions to `laravel\_%`?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a coffee cup to me.

Comment: @Eimantas  Yea, I suppose it does!  Going back, I see that when I created the user, I clicked `Grant all privileges on wildcard name (username\_%)`.  Not sure what this really means...

Comment: The _ could mean single character wildcard. The % means zero or more characters. So this means that you could login using any username starting with `username` and then some.

Comment: Or in this case, the `\_` means escaped underscore. So you can login with anything that starts with `username_`. E.g. `username_test00`, `username_migrations`, `username_backup`, etc.

Comment: I didn't know regular expressions could be used in MySQL usernames.  Do you know if this is a MySQL thing or just a PHPMyAdmin thing?

Comment: It's not regexp. It's mysql wildcards: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` and `_` are simply SQL wildcards. The [GRANT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) allows them:

> The _ and % wildcards are permitted when specifying database names in
>   GRANT statements that grant privileges at the database level.

You may notice that `_` is escaped (`\_`):

> if you want to use a `_` character as part of a
>   database name, you should specify it as `\_` in the GRANT statement, to
>   prevent the user from being able to access additional databases
>   matching the wildcard pattern; for example, GRANT ... ON `foo\_bar`.* TO ....

It's apparently a way to extend the privileges to any database that starts with `homestead_...`

Comment: This is exactly right. Probably when you created the user, you checked the box for "Grant all privileges on wildcard name (username\_%)."